# Is the proper class of all sets with binary operation being symmetric difference and identity being $\varnothing$ an element of $\textbf{Grp}$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, set-theory

My initial impression is yes because the construction fulfills the first-order axiomatization of a group; however, if this was the case then the forgetful functor from $\textbf{Grp} \to \textbf{Set}$ would not be well-defined on this object. This leads me to wonder if $\textbf{Grp}$ is a subcategory of a larger category of groups, where $\textbf{Grp}$ are groups which are simultaneously sets.

Comment: Groups are by definition sets. It is possible to define proper class-sized "groups", but then one would have further size issues and need to go up to "conglomerates" and higher levels.

Comment: Are set-theoretic groups and model-theoretic groups different then? What I mean by this is that groups can be defined as a non-empty set with a binary operation that satisfies associativity, identity, and inverses, but we can also define them axiomatically outside of set theory by considering a group to be any model of these three axioms: 1. $\forall x, x1 = x \wedge 1x = x$, 2. $\forall x, x x^{-1} = 1 \wedge x^{-1}x = 1$, 3. $ \forall x, \forall y, \forall z, (xy)z = x(yz)$. I don't think that models are required to be sets or else $\textbf{ZFC}$ would not have any models.

Comment: ZFC can have set size models, actually...

Comment: @2oovy: Models are required to be sets. If you know model theory, you have no doubt seen the following result: "a theory T is consistent iff it has a model". Since ZFC does not prove that ZFC is consistent (hopefully, see incompleteness), ZFC does not prove that ZFC has a model. Stronger theories can prove that ZFC has a model: but those theories can even construct *countable* models of ZFC (see Lowenheim-Skolem).